# Wickedpicker Always Show Current Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, wickedpicker

So I have settings for my wickedpicker. This is the setting

```
var options = {
            now: "12:35", //hh:mm 24 hour format only, defaults to current time 
            twentyFour: true, //Display 24 hour format, defaults to false 
            upArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-up', //The up arrow class selector to use, for custom CSS 
            downArrow: 'wickedpicker__controls__control-down', //The down arrow class selector to use, for custom CSS 
            close: 'wickedpicker__close', //The close class selector to use, for custom CSS 
            hoverState: 'hover-state', //The hover state class to use, for custom CSS 
            title: 'Setting Jam', //The Wickedpicker's title, 
            showSeconds: false, //Whether or not to show seconds, 
            secondsInterval: 1, //Change interval for seconds, defaults to 1 , 
            minutesInterval: 1, //Change interval for minutes, defaults to 1 
            beforeShow: null, //A function to be called before the Wickedpicker is shown 
            show: null, //A function to be called when the Wickedpicker is shown 
            clearable: false, //Make the picker's input clearable (has clickable "x")
        };

$('.time').wickedpicker(options);
```

Then I create an input field to store the time data

```
<input id="time_field" name="time_field" class="form-control time" placeholder="Time">
```

When I save, the data that goes into the database has the format 'hh : mm'.
Then I display it again in the edit form as a value.

```
<input id="time_field" name="time_field" class="form-control time" placeholder="Time" value="{{ $post->time }}">
```

But, the data does not appear. Data only shows default data which is 12:35.

Every time I will edit the data, the time field always displays 12:35, even though I have set the value in the input according to the data from the database. However, when I look at the source page, data from the database appears in the value input section.

Then I tried using jquery. When I retrieve data values from input, the retrieved data remains 12.35 which is the default data from wickedpicker.

```
var time = $('.time').val();
console.log(time) // output 12:35
```

also

```
var time = $('.time').wickedpicker('time');
console.log(time) // output 12:35
```

How do I set the time in the input field on wickedpicker from the database?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with that `now: "12:35"` you have as the first line in the options?

Comment: @rid i tried. I deleted the `now`option on options variable. Then the value that appears is current time instead of data from database

Comment: @KhoerulUmam, it's possible that the library can't parse the string if it contains spaces (see https://github.com/ericjgagnon/wickedpicker/blob/master/src/wickedpicker.js#L114). Try removing the spaces and keep "hh:mm" instead of "hh : mm".

Comment: @rid I have tried removing spaces in the database data, but it hasn't worked. I think that the function for setting the setting options is at the bottom of the code, so the data that appears in the rendering again becomes the default data.Thanks for the answer, I'll let you know later if there are results.

Answer (score 0):

```
def = { twentyFour: true, timeSeparator: ':'};
signInPicker = $('#SignIn').wickedpicker(def);
signOffPicker = $('#SignOff').wickedpicker(def);

$.ajax(top.$.rootUrl + '/Area/Controller/Action', function (data) {
    signInPicker.wickedpicker('setTime', 0, data.SignIn);
    signOffPicker.wickedpicker('setTime', 0, data.SignOff);
});
```